# How do i define Gson java class for this json input

Tags: java, json, gson

How do I define the tracks for Json for deserializing this json

```
"user": {
    "authority": "user",
    "title": "Renata Tebaldi Serenata Tebaldi [Disc 2]",
    "artist": "Renata Tebaldi",
    "tracks": {
        "1": "Track 01 - BELLINI: Vaga luna che inargenti",
        "2": "Track 02 - BELLINI: Per pieta bel ‘idol mio",
        "3": "Track 03 - MASCAGNI: M’ama ... Non m’ama",
        "4": "Track 04 - RESPIGHI: Notte",
        "5": "Track 05 - TOSTI: ‘A vuchella",
        "6": "Track 06 - DAVICO: O luna che fa lume",
        "7": "Track 07 - DONIZETTI: Me voglio fa ‘na casa",
        "8": "Track 08 - MASCAGNI: La tua Stella",
        "9": "Track 09 - TOSTI: Sogno",
        "10": "Track 10 -ROSSINI: L’invito",
        "11": "Track 11 - ZANDONAI: L’assiulo",
        "12": "Track 12 - CIMARA: Stormello",
        "13": "Track 13 - PONCHIELLI: Noi leggevamo insieme",
        "14": "Track 14 - MASCAGNI:  Serenato",
        "15": "Track 15 - PARISOTTI: Se tu m’ami",
        "16": "Track 16 - PARADISI: M’ha presa alla sua ragna",
        "17": "Track 17 - SCARLATTI: O cessati di piagarmi",
        "18": "Track 18 - GLUCK: O dell mio dolce ardor",
        "19": "Track 19 - RICCI: Il carrettiere del Vomero",
        "20": "Track 20 - MERCADANTE: La sposa del marinaro",
        "21": "Track 21 - BELLINI:  Malliconia, ninfa gemtile",
        "22": "Track 22 - PUCCINI: E l’luccelino"
    }
},
```

My definition of User is as follows

```
public class UnitiCoreUser
{
    private String authority;
    private String artist;
    private String title;


    public String getAuthority()
    {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority)
    {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist)
    {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

My problem is track because the elements within are not fixed by name, i.e they are all the same but are labelled 1,2,3,4,... so can t just have an array of tracks.

e.g Track[] tracks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, String> tracks;
```

Here is an example (the class you showed along with the JSON you showed didn't quite match up either):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestApp {

    public TestApp() {
        String test = "{\"user\":{\"authority\":\"user\",\"title\":\"Renata Tebaldi Serenata Tebaldi [Disc 2]\",\"artist\":\"Renata Tebaldi\",\"tracks\":{\"1\":\"Track 01 - BELLINI: Vaga luna che inargenti\",\"2\":\"Track 02 - BELLINI: Per pieta bel \u2018idol mio\",\"3\":\"Track 03 - MASCAGNI: M\u2019ama ... Non m\u2019ama\",\"4\":\"Track 04 - RESPIGHI: Notte\",\"5\":\"Track 05 - TOSTI: \u2018A vuchella\",\"6\":\"Track 06 - DAVICO: O luna che fa lume\",\"7\":\"Track 07 - DONIZETTI: Me voglio fa \u2018na casa\",\"8\":\"Track 08 - MASCAGNI: La tua Stella\",\"9\":\"Track 09 - TOSTI: Sogno\",\"10\":\"Track 10 -ROSSINI: L\u2019invito\",\"11\":\"Track 11 - ZANDONAI: L\u2019assiulo\",\"12\":\"Track 12 - CIMARA: Stormello\",\"13\":\"Track 13 - PONCHIELLI: Noi leggevamo insieme\",\"14\":\"Track 14 - MASCAGNI:  Serenato\",\"15\":\"Track 15 - PARISOTTI: Se tu m\u2019ami\",\"16\":\"Track 16 - PARADISI: M\u2019ha presa alla sua ragna\",\"17\":\"Track 17 - SCARLATTI: O cessati di piagarmi\",\"18\":\"Track 18 - GLUCK: O dell mio dolce ardor\",\"19\":\"Track 19 - RICCI: Il carrettiere del Vomero\",\"20\":\"Track 20 - MERCADANTE: La sposa del marinaro\",\"21\":\"Track 21 - BELLINI:  Malliconia, ninfa gemtile\",\"22\":\"Track 22 - PUCCINI: E l\u2019luccelino\"}}}";
        UnitiCoreUser user = new Gson().fromJson(test, UnitiCoreUser.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestApp();
    }

    public class UnitiCoreUser {

        private User user;

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
    }

    class User {

        public String authority;
        private String artist;
        private String title;
        Map<Integer, String> tracks;

        public String getAuthority() {
            return authority;
        }

        public void setAuthority(String authority) {
            this.authority = authority;
        }

        public String getArtist() {
            return artist;
        }

        public void setArtist(String artist) {
            this.artist = artist;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public Map<Integer, String> getTracks() {
            return tracks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay using map of strings was the solution, thx.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
Map<String,String> tracks
```

It will automatically be deserialized to map.

Comment: In a list of tracks, `int` seems more useable as the tracks key then keeping it as a `String` IMO hence my answer suggesting to use `int`

Comment: In the object above the keys are coming as String so you have to use strings otherwise it won't get deserialize. Also we will have to use Interger object, int does not work with Map if we want to use integer, but in this case we can't.

Comment: True on the Integer part (Use to int from C#) but Im surprised it wont deserialize?

Comment: Yes, it will throw exception if Interger is used. As the keys in 'tracks' field are Strings.

Comment: I just tested now it doesnt exception

Comment: I tried it once, it gave me exception. Can you share the code with me somehow?

Comment: either way +1 your solution is pretty much the same as mine

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it _can_ handle non-numeric track numbers schemes for various media, despite the OP would have to manage maps instead of lists or arrays across the app.

Answer (score 0):

Gson has type adapters that can deal with some oddities. These type adapters can read/write JSON elements mapping them to/from classes, and make some additional checks (say, array-like map verification).

```java
public final class SequentiveMapTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final ConstructorConstructor constructorConstructor = new ConstructorConstructor(ImmutableMap.of(
            List.class, type -> new ArrayList<>()
    ));

    private SequentiveMapTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        if ( !List.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final Type type = typeToken.getType();
        final Type elementType = $Gson$Types.getCollectionElementType(type, rawType);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new SequentiveMapTypeAdapter<>(
                (ObjectConstructor<? extends List<Object>>) constructorConstructor.get(typeToken),
                (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType))
        );
        return typeAdapter.nullSafe();
    }

    private static final class SequentiveMapTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<List<E>> {

        private final ObjectConstructor<? extends List<E>> objectConstructor;
        private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;

        private SequentiveMapTypeAdapter(final ObjectConstructor<? extends List<E>> objectConstructor, final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
            this.objectConstructor = objectConstructor;
            this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<E> list) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public List<E> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();
            final List<E> list = objectConstructor.construct();
            for ( int i = 1; in.hasNext(); i++ ) {
                final String name = in.nextName();
                if ( !name.equals(String.valueOf(i)) ) {
                    throw new JsonParseException("Expected " + i + " but was name " + name);
                }
                final E element = elementTypeAdapter.read(in);
                list.add(element);
            }
            in.endObject();
            return list;
        }

    }

}
```

Then your mapping object should be aware of how to convert the JSON object to a list or an array by annotating the respective field:

```java
final class UnitiCoreUser {

    String authority;
    String artist;
    String title;

    @JsonAdapter(SequentiveMapTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    List<String> tracks;

}
```

Then it will work:

```java
final UnitiCoreUser unitiCoreUser = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, UnitiCoreUser.class);
for ( final String track : unitiCoreUser.tracks ) {
    System.out.println(track);
}
```

Output:

```
Track 01 - BELLINI: Vaga luna che inargenti
Track 02 - BELLINI: Per pieta bel ‘idol mio
Track 03 - MASCAGNI: M’ama ... Non m’ama
Track 04 - RESPIGHI: Notte
Track 05 - TOSTI: ‘A vuchella
Track 06 - DAVICO: O luna che fa lume
Track 07 - DONIZETTI: Me voglio fa ‘na casa
Track 08 - MASCAGNI: La tua Stella
Track 09 - TOSTI: Sogno
Track 10 -ROSSINI: L’invito
Track 11 - ZANDONAI: L’assiulo
Track 12 - CIMARA: Stormello
Track 13 - PONCHIELLI: Noi leggevamo insieme
Track 14 - MASCAGNI:  Serenato
Track 15 - PARISOTTI: Se tu m’ami
Track 16 - PARADISI: M’ha presa alla sua ragna
Track 17 - SCARLATTI: O cessati di piagarmi
Track 18 - GLUCK: O dell mio dolce ardor
Track 19 - RICCI: Il carrettiere del Vomero
Track 20 - MERCADANTE: La sposa del marinaro
Track 21 - BELLINI:  Malliconia, ninfa gemtile
Track 22 - PUCCINI: E l’luccelino
```

Comment: That seems like alot of unnecessary work when a `Map` an simply be used, but a vlaid solution none the less

Comment: Why using a map to mimic arrays? If a JSON provider uses odd array-like maps, why not both convert and verify them making ready-to-use lists?

Comment: Well you now loose the track number (yes its jumbled in the String), which I'm not sure if OP needs but as I said its a solution none the less

Comment: @DavidKroukamp _you now loose the track number_ -- well, it's a subject to debate... `Map<Integer, String>` can't also handle track numbers like `A1`, `A2`, `B1` for cassettes, vinyls, etc.

Comment: @dhruvtailor The OP's probably trying to build a domain model, and the issue OP's faced with is that is not clear whether it's representative layer (DTO), or the domain (if those layers are mixed up). If it's just representation, and the map you've suggested won't span across layers, the OP would anyway have to map maps to domain model by applying _so much of overwork_.

Comment: thx, but the other solutions work for me.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I'm wondering how _`Track[] tracks;`_ (from the original question) aligns to maps that loosely mimic arrays, but yeah you'll do the same across your app, not in the type adapter... Well, then... I would like to suggest to accept @dhruv's answer then because it can handle non-numeric track numbers schemes, that are not necessarily 1, 2, and then always 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using a property Map<String,String> tracks